# change shell in Solaris/SunOS for your user only wihtout access to /etc/passwd

Tags: shell, ssh, solaris

How do I set the shell in Solaris/SunOS for my user only, without access to `/etc/passwd` or any other `su` stuff?

It should thereafter work both for interactive `ssh` (1) and `ssh` when you send commands (2).

`uname -a` says `SunOS ... 5.10 Generic_148889-04 i86pc i386 i86pc`

**Edit in response to comments and answers**

There is no `chsh`.

I can't do `/usr/bin/passwd -e` - permission denied.

The default shell is bash. I would like zsh.

I already tried to set the `SHELL` environment variable manually, and start the shell manually in the `.profile` file, only this doesn't work for my **second case** (2): `ssh user@host command` will run `command` in bash.

As compared to getting my preferred shell when I login, it is minor, so the workaround is certainly worth mentioning, only, my intention with this question was to get it right the right way. Because it just relates to one user, I thought it was doable without involving the SA, but now I'm less certain. (But any workaround that solves (1) and (2) is cool, for sure.)

Comment: Can you state what your current login shell is and what shell you want to set instead ?

Comment: To anyone reading @jlliagre above, check out his [answer](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/80964/13136) and the comments below it.

Comment: @jlliagre: No, I get an error message saying bash cannot find my zsh `noglob`.

Comment: @jlliagre: Without the solution below, bash says there is no such command (which makes sense), so of course the problem is that bash runs the command, and the solution is to have zsh run the command, and then it works. Try `noglob echo *` - bash will fail on `noglob` but zsh will echo `*`.

Comment: @jlliagre: command, for example, is `noglob echo *`.

Comment: Okay, my mistake. `ssh` is indeed using the remote user default shell to execute the command, otherwise, running a builtin command like `noglob` wouldn't have been possible. Removing my pointless comments up there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `SHELL=newshell; exec "$SHELL"` trick has already been covered.

Now, if you also want commands run over ssh to use your new shell. If the current login shell is `bash`, you can add this to your `~/.bashrc`:

```
if [ -n "$BASH_EXECUTION_STRING" ]; then
  export SHELL=/bin/zsh
  exec "$SHELL" -c "$BASH_EXECUTION_STRING"
fi
```

That will execute `something` with the new shell whenever `bash` is started with `bash -c something` **and** it reads `~/.bashrc`.

Shells started with `bash -c something` generally do not read the `~/.bashrc`. An exception is when those `bash` are called by `sshd` or `rshd`, or upon `bash -ic something`.

You could add a check for `[ -n "$SSH_CONNECTION" ]` if you only want to cover the `ssh` case.

Comment: Yes, the `$BASH_EXECUTION_STRING` chunk in `.bashrc` and the "trick" in `.profile` work.

Comment: Why not make the test `[[ $- != *i* ]]`, i.e. this bash instance isn't interactive?

Comment: @Gilles: Care to explain how that would be an improvement?

Comment: @EmanuelBerg Why would you want an explicit call `bash -ic 'somecommand'` to run `zsh -ic 'somecommand'` instead?

Comment: @Gilles: Are you saying it should be like above, only the condition changed into what you propose?

Answer (score 8):

#### method #1: with `chsh`

Usually you can use the command `chsh` to change your shell without having to have access to the `/etc/passwd`. This is the file that typically lists your default shell, for example:

```
saml:x:500:501:Sam M. (local):/home/saml:/bin/zsh
```

A normal user may only change the login shell for his/her own account, the super user i.e. root user may change the login shell for any account. You can see what shells are available on your system with this command:

```
$ chsh --list-shells
/bin/sh
/bin/bash
/sbin/nologin
/bin/dash
/bin/tcsh
/bin/csh
/bin/zsh
```

To change your shell you can use this command:

```
$ chsh -s /bin/zsh saml
Changing shell for saml.
Password: 
Shell changed.
```

The effect is obvious if you look in the `/etc/passwd` file:

```
$ grep saml /etc/passwd
saml:x:500:501:Sam M. (local):/home/saml:/bin/zsh
```

You won't see the change immediately. You'll have to logout/login to see it:

```
[saml@grinchy]~% echo $SHELL
/bin/zsh
```

#### method #2: `/usr/bin/passwd -e`

If you don't have access to the command `chsh` which apparently you don't on Solaris, and you don't have root access to change it in `/etc/passwd`, you might be able to still do the same with this command:

```
$ /usr/bin/passwd -e
```

#### method #3: manually set it method

If neither of the above methods are an option you're basically left with this last option, which is to add one of following to your existing shell's login files:

1. *default shell: /bin/csh or /bin/tcsh*

   Add the following lines to `$HOME/.login`:

   ```
   setenv SHELL=/bin/bash
   exec $SHELL
   ```
2. *default shell: /bin/bash*

   Add the following to `$HOME/.bash_profile`:

   ```
   export SHELL=/bin/zsh
   exec $SHELL
   ```

Some additional things to consider with the above, you can make them more bullet proof by performing a check to see if the current $SHELL already is `/bin/bash` for example, prior to setting it. If it is, do nothing, otherwise go ahead and perform the `exec $SHELL`.

#### References

- [Howto: Changing Linux Login Shell](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/howto-change-linux-unix-freebsd-login-shell/)
- [chsh for Solaris](http://www.one-eyed-alien.net/~brooks/software/chsh-solaris/index.shtml)

Comment: Unfortunately, Solaris doesn't provide chsh, so unless the local admin installed it, that won't help here.

Comment: @alanc - what about `/usr/bin/passwd -e`?

Comment: `passwd -e` won't work either, unless the user account is centrally stored (NIS, LDAP, ...) which isn't the case here.

Comment: @jlliagre: So certain are you? I use `passwd -e` to change my shell on my Solaris systems which use neither NIS nor LDAP.

Comment: I guess the `exec` in `.profile` won't lead to an endless loop because Bash doesn't read this file when invoked this way ...?

Comment: @bahamat So certain I am. The question is about Solaris 10 which had that constraint. It is no more present indeed with Solaris 11 passwd command.

Comment: @bahamat - that's what I seemed to recall as well, but I don't have access currently to either Solaris 10 or 11 systems so I couldn't confirm. I did find this thread which mentions you can use `usermod -s /bin/bash USERNAME` to change it too on Solaris. http://serverfault.com/questions/333979/solaris-change-the-default-shell

Comment: @jlliagre: Yep :-( As soon as I posted that I second guessed myself and went looking for a man page. The [S10](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19253-01/816-5165/6mbb0m9n4/index.html) does state that it's only directory accounts.

Comment: @sim: yes, but `usermod` can't be used by an ordinary user.

Comment: @tripleee - no the `exec` takes care of this.

Comment: @bahamat - so I guess the only option is the `.profile` mod.

Comment: You may want to add that if the login shell is csh, you need to modify `.login` and use `csh` syntax instead of `.profile`. I would also check that the current shell is not already `bash` before executing $SHELL to avoid that little dance on `bash --login` for instance.

Comment: @StephaneChazelas - see my edits and let me know if they address your comment. I only 1/2 understood what you're telling me.

Comment: I made an edit to the [question](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/80953/13136).

Answer (score 4):

You can't do it with a vanilla Solaris installation. A simple workaround would be to modify your profile to exec the wanted shell.

Eg, assuming `/etc/passwd` states your shell is `/bin/bash` but you prefer `/bin/ksh`:

```
$ tail -2 ~/.bash_profile
export SHELL=/bin/ksh
exec $SHELL
```

Beware not to lock you out with a typo or not to enter an infinite loop with bogus exec or logic.

Comment: Setting `$SHELL` would also make sure that commands that start a shell (like `xterm`, `vi`...) also start your new prefered shell.

Comment: @StephaneChazelas Indeed, answer updated.

Comment: I did this already, including what @StephaneChazelas suggested, only, for `ssh user@host command` it still tries to use bash, so it won't work for `noglob` and such zsh stuff. A workaround to that - include the shell in the command?

Comment: Can you please clearly state what is the shell set for your account and the shell you want it to be replaced with ?

Comment: @jlliagre: I made an edit to the [question](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/80953/13136).